# Using Scanner and Arrays's to add BigInts

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is a project from school, but i'm only asking for help in the logic on one small part of it.  I got most of it figured out.

I'm being given a file with lines of string integers, for example:

```
1234  123
12 153 23
1234
```

I am to read each line, compute the sum, and then go to the next one to produce this:

```
1357
188
1234
```

I'm stuck on the scanner part.

```
public static void doTheThing(Scanner input) {

    int[] result = new int[MAX_DIGITS];
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {

        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner linesc = new Scanner(line);

        while(linesc.hasNext()) {
            String currentLine = linesc.next();
            int[] currentArray = convertArray(stringToArray(currentLine));
            result = addInt(result, currentArray);
        }
        result = new int[MAX_DIGITS];

    }


}
```

In a nutshell, I want to grab each big integer, put it an array of numbers, add them, and then i'll do the rest later.

What this is doing it's basically reading all the lines and adding everything and putting it into a single array.

What i'm stuck on is how do I read each line, add, reset the value to 0, and then read the next line?  I've been at this for hours and i'm mind stumped.

Edit 01:  I realize now that I should be using another scanner to read each line, but now i'm getting an error that looks like an infinite loop?

Edit 02:  Ok, so after more hints and advice, I'm past that error, but now it's doing exactly what the original problem is.

Final Edit:  Heh....fixed it.  I was forgetting to reset the value to "0" before printing each value.  So it makes sense that it was adding all of the values.

Yay....coding is fun....

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik, I forgot about the numbers.

Comment: `next()` reads single token, if you want to read entire line use `nextLine()`.

Comment: @Pshemo, nextLine() will take the entire line of string integers.  I need each string integer to be added on the line and then move down to the next one.

For example, if I have 111 and 111, I want 111 to be shoved into an array, and added to a counter array.  Then I want it to grab the second 111 and added it to the counter array to produce 222 on that line.

Comment: Then handle that line (and its integer) with separate Scanner... This way you will also know if there are more integers in that line or not.

Comment: @Pshemo, what do you mean?

Comment: Pshemo means that you can have two separate Scanners.  One Scanner reads each line using `nextLine()`.  Then the second Scanner reads the `String` that the first Scanner has read, using `nextInt()`.  And you add up the numbers read by the second Scanner.  (@Pshemo, do tell me if you actually meant something different).

Comment: Scanner already allows you to iterate over numbers via `nextInt()` (with little help of `hasNextInt()` so we would know when to stop). So you can do it directly on your input. You can process those values when you get them, why you want to put them in array?

Comment: @Pshemo, I made a comment on your hints (thanks for that!).  It's part of the assignment.  The string integers are big integers and I can't use the java class for it.  That's why I need to use an array.

Comment: About your previous edit: NoSuchElementException is thrown when you call `next...()` but there is nothing to read. To avoid it you can use `hasNext...()` and based on result decide if you want to read next element or not.

Comment: If the numbers are too big for `int` or `long`, then use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` and pass the resulting `String` to the `BigInteger` constructor.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I made a new edit 02, and I can't break past this logic block of why it's basically adding everything together and putting it into an array.

Comment: So where are you constructing a `BigInteger`?  I would suggest you read up on how the `BigInteger` class works.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, the method that I created, addTheThings, does exactly what BigInteger.add would do.  The adding isn't the problem that i'm having.

Comment: So you've got logic errors in the methods you haven't shown us?  OK.  Now what do you expect anyone here to do about it?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem no no, that's not what I said.  The addTheThings function has no errors and no logic problems.  It does exactly what BigIntegert.add would do.  There are no logic problems.  

The logic problems I am having in my mind are happening in the "doTheThing" method where the scanning/reading is happening, which I have presented/edited already.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the code that creates the `BigInteger` objects or adds them up.  You've written everything else you need.  So there's nothing left to help you with.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem as I've already said: the problem is not in "addTheThings".  You may assume the code that adds the array of integers together is correct and is working.  You may also assume that the original problem in the title is the part of the code that I need help with and nothing else.

Either way, i've a final edit where I figured out what my problem was.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasNext` method of the Scanner class can be used to check if there is any data available in stream or not. Accordingly, `next` method used to retrieve next continuous sequence of characters without white space characters. Here use of the hasNext method as condition of if doesn't make any sense as what you want is to check if the there are any numerical data left in the current line. You can use `next(String pattern)`.

In addition, you can try this solution even though it is not optimal solution...

```
// In a loop
String line = input.nextLine(); //return entire line & descard newline character.
String naw[] = line.split(" "); //split line into sub strings.
/*naw contains numbers of the current line in form of string array.
Now you can perfom your logic after converting string to int.*/
```

I would also like to  mention  that it can easily & efficiently be done using java-8 streams.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to abandon the `Scanner` altogether, let [`java.nio.io.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to the reading for you and then just handle each line:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/my/file.txt"))
     .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum())
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would be using the BufferedReader insted of the Scanner like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path"));
    String line = "";
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        String[] arr = line.split(" ");
        for(String num : arr)
        {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(num);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the level you're on, I think you should consider this solution. By using only the scanner, you can split the lines into an array of tokens, then iterate and sum the tokens by parsing them and validating that they're not empty.

```
import java.util.*;

class SumLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(S.hasNext()) {
            String[] tokens = S.nextLine().split(" ");
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if(!tokens[i].equals("")) sum += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }   
    }
}
```

[image: Running the class:]